# How can I recover a .pages document with only an iPad?

Tags: data-recovery, ipad, iwork-pages

I had this problem a few hours ago, and was really frustrated by it, so I'd thought I'd share:

Scenario:

- My computer with Pages has died
- I have a Pages file on a flash drive that I need **now**
- I don't want to reformat the document from a plain text version
- I have an iPad with Pages
- I can't email my file to my iPad because Pages files are really folders

How can I recover my file?

Answer (score 2):

To recover the file:

1. Use Winrar (or another archive utility) to zip the document into a ZIP archive.
2. Email the ZIP archive to yourself.
3. Download the document onto your iPad, which will unzip the file and present it as a Pages file, retaining all formatting.